# EmberJS sort an ArrayController based on an ItemController or global property?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to sort an ArrayController of related objects on a calculated property (`relevance`).  Relevance is calculated based on the primary model you are viewing.

The trouble seems to be that while you can decorate a model with a controller, adding display logic/properties there you can't sort on those properties.  (See: [Ember ArrayController cannot be sorted by property defined in itemController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082228/ember-arraycontroller-cannot-be-sorted-by-property-defined-in-itemcontroller))

I've created a JSBin that captures most of this: http://jsbin.com/guluxaco/1/edit

I know I can get this working by pushing the relevance property down to the model but don't think that is appropriate for the model to reach up to another controller (or a global property)

I see two approaches:

1) push `relevance` down to the model (related objects).  In that case where should I store the current model (primary object)?

2) Get the ArrayController to re-sort somehow?  Maybe sort or decorate the model in the route?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and I came up with a solution, so, what I did is to change your models like this:

```
model: function() {
  return [Ember.Object.create({color: 'red'}), 
        Ember.Object.create({color: 'yellow'}), 
        Ember.Object.create({color: 'blue'})];
}
```

and then, your Colors controller to this:

```
App.ColorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['mood'],
  sortProperties: ['relevance'],

  contentChanged: function() {
    Ember.run.once(this, function() {
      this.get('content').forEach(function(color) {
        color.set('relevance', color.get('color') === this.get('controllers.mood.mood') ? 1 : 0);
      }, this);
    });
  }.observes('content.@each', 'controllers.mood.mood')
});
```

hope this helps, I changed your jsbin to this code and it is working.

Comment: now that I read your question again, I think this solution is what you don't want to do, put the property in the model.